# How to correctly declare FontSet in PSD EngineData?

Tags: photoshop, psd

I'm trying to generate PSD file in my application, with some text layers (`TySh`). Its EngineData format is pretty simple, but unfortunately have no documentation, and i got stuck with FontSet field:

```
/FontSet [
<<
  /Name (ADomIno)
  /Script 8
  /FontType 1
  /Synthetic 3
>>
<<
  /Name (ADomIno)
  /Script 8
  /FontType 1
  /Synthetic 0
>>
<<
  /Name (AdobeInvisFont)
  /Script 0
  /FontType 0
  /Synthetic 0
>>
<<
  /Name (MyriadPro-Regular)
  /Script 0
  /FontType 0
  /Synthetic 0
>>
]
```

This is Photoshop-generated data, i only omitted UTF-16 for easy-reading.

So... I can't understand, why font a_DomIno written as ADomIno. Why some fonts has "-Regular" suffix, but some has not. What means "Script", "FontType" and "Synthetic" fields. Why some fonts has two records with different fields, but other ones - only one.

There's no info in Adobe PSD format documentation, Photoshop Scripting Reference and Photoshop SDK. Projects like psd.rb or psd.js targets to parse file and has no useful info too.

Maybe someone knows?

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/
is a good place to start looking for psd fiel format info. 

The PSD.js module is also a good source of documentation since the creator has taken time to explain what happens in each file to parse the psd http://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/docs/lib/psd/file.coffee.html

Comment: Thank you, but i seen it - there's no info about it. I used this documentation and existing source codes, but it's all about reading PSD files - not writing, especially TySH structure.

Comment: The file applies to both writing and reading. the file tells you exactly where the file's info is stored and how. so all you need to do is put the info you wish to push in a psd file in the specified place

Comment: Please re-read my question. TySh EngineData is sub-format, it even not described in official documentation. It's pretty simple to **read** it, but not to write **properly**. I able to generate PSD file with text layers, but when i try to open it in Photoshop some fonts are good, but some are need replacement ("some fonts used in this document are missing" - and yep, this font is installed and its name is in font list). My problem is how to specify font name in TySh EngineData structure.

Comment: After some digging i discovered why there is little to no doc on it: its no longer used according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1jdbr0/layervault_breaks_open_the_psd_file_format_and/cbdxr0v/) reddit comment on the PSD.rb lib.

So trying to do this is quite a futile effort unless you're willing to get comfy with a lot of psd files and the PSD engine

Comment: You mistakes. "tySh" structure is deprecated now, but "TySh" and EngineData used by all modern Photoshop versions. EngineData can be found in another structure too (text-related, but not required).

Comment: I notice i can generate PSD file (with text layers via TySh and EngineData) which can be successfully opened in Photoshop. Problem is in font names only. Some fonts Photoshop can recognize, some of them can't - and requires to replace it with any other. Photoshop saves font names in strange way, and they don't matches its regular names.